# ZSH iterate through string array containing spaces

Tags: zsh, array, string

I am trying to write a ZSH script which will iterate through a series of strings that contain spaces.

First, I'll `set -A` the array:

`set -A a "this is" "a test" "of the" "emergency broadcast system"`

From here, I'll try to iterate through it using a basic `for` loop, making sure to wrap the array in quotes to handle the spaces:

`for i in "$a"; do echo "${a[$i]}"`

However, this throws the following error:

`` zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `is a test ...' ``

I've been playing around with this for a bit, even trying setting the delimiter to "\n" since I think the issue is the array is using spaces as delimiters, but even doing:

`a=(IFS=$'\n';"this is" "a test" "of the" "emergency broadcast system")`

followed by:

`for i in "$a"; do echo "${a[$i]}"; done`

yields the same ZSH error.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with `$IFS`. You are simply getting the syntax wrong.

This is how you would normally iterate over an array in `zsh`:

```bash
% arr=( 'this is' 'a test' 'of the' 'emergency broadcast system' )
% for str in "$arr[@]"; do print -- $str; done
this is
a test
of the
emergency broadcast system
%
```

Alternatively, if you actually need to iterate over the array indices, then you could do it like this:

```bash
% for (( i = 1; i <= $#arr[@]; i++ )) do; print -- $arr[i]; done
```

Or like this:

```bash
% for i in {1..$#arr[@]} do; print -- $arr[i]; done
```

Of course, if you just want to print the elements of the array as a vertical list, then you don't need to use a loop at all:

```bash
% print -l -- "$arr[@]"
this is
a test
of the
emergency broadcast system
%
```

Comment: `identity="iPhone Distribution: Apple Inc."; command=(codesign -fs $identity Payload/xx.app); $(echo $command)`, how can I treat `$identity` as a single string?

Comment: Solution: embrace with quotes and use `eval` to explain the quotes correctly, i.e, `folder="My Pictures"; command=(ls -l \""$folder"\"); eval "$command[*]"`

Comment: If you are using `eval` for _anything,_ that’s usually a sign you’re doing it wrong. Just use `"$identity"`, with double quotes.