# How do I Iterate over an array of spaced string pairs in zsh?

Tags: zsh, array, string

I was reading the post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1686176/zsh-iterate-through-string-array-containing-spaces) and tried out the solutions.

However, the following does not produce any output. What am I missing?

```bash
arr=( '102 351' '576 324' '427 321' )
for str in "$arr[@]";                                                                                                                                                                                  ✔ 
do ./findgcd $str | cat >> output;
done;
```

`output` file remains empty but no error is seen.

Comment: is findgcd executable ? what is this a script ? a program ? if its script make sure to use `shabang` and have permission to execute `chmod u+x ./findgcd`

Comment: yes, it works individually for all those values.

Comment: does it have `shabang` as first line ? `#!/usr/bin/zsh` ?

Comment: No, I'm running it directly on the terminal.

Comment: what is the value of `echo $?` just after you execute ? it should be zero

Comment: yup, its 0 a'right.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other shells, `zsh` does not automatically split variables on whitespace, so the `findgcd` call is being passed a single string. The `showArgs` function in the script below demonstrates what happens and how you can force word-spliting with the `$=` expansion:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

showArgs() {
    printf -- '%-9s:' "${1}"
    shift
    printf ' "%s"' "$@"
    print
}

arr=( '102 351' '576 324' '427 321' )
for str in "$arr[@]"; do
    showArgs 'No split' ${str}
    showArgs 'Split' ${=str}
    # ./findgcd ${=str} >> output
    findgcd ${=str}
    print
done
```

Output:

```
No split : "102 351"
Split    : "102" "351"
3

No split : "576 324"
Split    : "576" "324"
36

No split : "427 321"
Split    : "427" "321"
1
```

---

Another way to process an array as pairs in `zsh`:

```bash
arr=(
  102 351
  576 324
  427 321
)
for a b in $arr; do
    showArgs 'pairs' $a $b
    findgcd $a $b
done
```

Output:

```
pairs    : "102" "351"
3
pairs    : "576" "324"
36
pairs    : "427" "321"
1
```